# OAuth2 not working with https in redirect_uri

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm using https in redirect_uri field of OAuth2. But when I connect to google client, I'm redirect to http url, not https. Here is a part of the code:

```
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($secret);
$client->setRedirectUri("https://mydomain/myphp.php");
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'));
```

I use the example from http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/

When I run the script, it shows me a "Connect Me!" message and when I click on it, the browser ask my permition to access my google account. After I agree, it would must redirect me to the address in setRedirectUri, in HTTPS mode. But google api redirect me the same url but in http mode.

Some idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show (the relevant bits of) a browser trace?

Comment: I added some more information. I hope you can understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all is working, but after successful authentication on https your own code redirects you to a cleaned URL on plain http.  Check the sample code that you copied after receiving and exchanging the `code` ("Step 2") and change the construction of the URL so that it uses https instead of https.

Comment: Exactly !!!! So easy to see!! Sometimes we are so blind about our mistakes! Thank you very much!

Comment: FWIW: a browser trace would have made this obvious right away; pretty useful for your own debugging...